# Structure of solutions of $f(z)^n - c = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)$ be a second degree polynomial, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and a constant $c \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ with $|c| < 1$. We have the equation

\begin{equation}
f(z)^n - c = 0.
\end{equation}

For a specific $f(z)$, I have a proof that we obtain $2n$ roots $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_{2n}$ and they have the following structure

\begin{equation}
|z_i| < |c|, ~ i = 1,\ldots,n, \quad |z_j| > |c|, ~ j = n+1,\ldots,2n.
\end{equation}

Let $c_k$ be the $k$-th complex root of $c^{1/n}$. Is the following immediate?

\begin{equation}
\forall i \in \{n+1,\ldots,2n\} ~ \exists j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}: f(z_i) = f(z_j) = c_k.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because $|z|$ has no particular meaning here; since the roots of $f(z)^n-c$ can be translated via $f(z-a)^n-c$, you can make that circle enclose whichever roots you like. In particular, a counterexample is

$$f(z)=z^2-4,\qquad g(z)=f(z)^2-2=0,$$

where the four roots of $g$ are

$$z_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{4-\sqrt2},\qquad z_{3,4}=\pm\sqrt{4+\sqrt2}.$$

As you can see, $|z_{1,2}|^2=4-\sqrt2<2^2$ and $|z_{3,4}|^2=4+\sqrt2>2^2$, but both $z_1$ and $z_2$ correspond to solutions to $f(z)=\sqrt 2$, and $z_{3,4}$ are solutions to $f(z)=-\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The fact that $|c| < 1$ does not simplify anything here? So, I guess I need to use properties of my particular $f(z)$ to try to prove the conjecture.

Comment: @Ritz No, if you replace $f(z)\mapsto f(4z)/2$ and $c\mapsto c/4=1/2$ in the above you get exactly the same counterexample with additionally $|c|<1$.